# Fusion: create "headless" virtual machines?

Tags: windows, linux, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion, headless

Is there a way to run a VM in Fusion that starts when the machine does, but I can then access via Remote Desktop (Windows) or ssh (Linux) rather than by opening the Fusion app, starting the VM, and then connecting however I'd prefer (rdp/ssh)?

I know this is possible with VMware Server for both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a couple [answers](http://drchriswilson.blogspot.com/2009/12/vmware-fusion-3-headless.html) [elsewhere](http://morethanseven.net/2008/09/27/headless-vmware-fusion.html).

Quoting from my [first](http://drchriswilson.blogspot.com/2009/12/vmware-fusion-3-headless.html) source:

> 1. You may or may not want to add the location of `vmrun` to your default
>      path. I chose not to as I will mostly
>      be interacting with `vmrun` through
>      shell scripts.
> 2. To Launch the virtual machine named `VA-LAMP.vmx` which is located in the
>      standard virtual machine directory
>      enter the following command into the
>      Terminal app.
>
> `/Library/Application\ Support/VMware\ Fusion/vmrun -T fusion start /Users/USERNAME/Documents/Virtual\ Machines.localized/VA-LAMP.vmwarevm/VA-LAMP.vmx nogui`
>
> To make this a command to launch the
>   headless terminal from a file on the
>   desktop just open text edit and enter
>   the following text
>
> `#!/bin/bash /Library/Application\ Support/VMware\ Fusion/vmrun -T fusion start /Users/USERNAME/Documents/Virtual\ Machines.localized/VA-LAMP.vmwarevm/VA-LAMP.vmx nogui`
>
> Save the file as plain text to the
>   desktop as `headless.command`
>
> Now to make it executable fire up the
>   terminal application and type
>
> `chmod +x $HOME/Desktop/headless.command`

And the [second](http://morethanseven.net/2008/09/27/headless-vmware-fusion.html):

> To enable it you need to run the following on your console: `defaults write com.vmware.fusion fluxCapacitor -bool YES`

Comment: I think that `defaults write com.vmware.fusion fluxCapacitor -bool YES` is only necessary/available in VMWare Fusion 2. In version 3, [that option was removed, much to the chagrin of some users](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1400122). However, the first set of instructions you posted worked just fine for me in version 3 on my Mac.

Comment: @Paul, confirming that `defaults write...` is not required. I'm running `vmrun` without no problem, without the `defaults...` command.

Answer (score 0):

I created an example here for my own convenience:

```
$ lamp start
2013-12-12T14:21:11.562| ServiceImpl_Opener: PID 1666
$ vmrun list
Total running VMs: 1
/Users/alex/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/fusion6\centos\64x\minimal\LAMP.vmwarevm/fusion6\centos\64x\minimal\LAMP.vmx
$ lamp stop
$ vmrun list
Total running VMs: 0
```

The script is at https://github.com/AlexanderAllen/lamp.

This assumes you have `vmrun` somewhere in your `$PATH`.

Comment: Please besides showing the link copy the script here. The link can stop functioning in the future and in addition the script is very short.